# Count Rows in Doctrine QueryBuilder

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine's QueryBuilder to build a query, and I want to get the total count of results from the query.

```
$repository = $em->getRepository('FooBundle:Foo');

$qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('n')
        ->where('n.bar = :bar')
        ->setParameter('bar', $bar);

$query = $qb->getQuery();

//this doesn't work
$totalrows = $query->getResult()->count();
```

I just want to run a count on this query to get the total rows, but not return the actual results.  (After this count query, I'm going to further modify the query with maxResults for pagination.)

Comment: you just want to return the number of results? your code is not very clear. why doesn't getQuery() work?

Comment: For building pagination with doctrine2 have a look at this extension: https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions

Comment: @Stefan it is now part of ORM. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html

Answer (score 556, accepted):

Something like:

```php
$qb = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('count(account.id)');
$qb->from('ZaysoCoreBundle:Account','account');

$count = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Some folks feel that expressions are somehow better than just using straight DQL. One even went so far as to edit a four year old answer. I rolled his edit back. Go figure.

Comment: He didn't ask for a count without predicates (`bar = $bar`) ;)

Comment: He accepted your answer so I guess all is well.  I was under the impression that he only wanted a count without the overhead of actually retrieving the rows which my example shows.  There is of course no reason why where conditions could not be added.

Comment: +1 for using getSingleScalarResult(). using `count()` on `$query->getResult()` is actually making the query return the results (which is what he *didn't* want). i think this should be accepted answer

Comment: The most portable way is to do `$qb->select($qb->expr()->count('account.id'))`

Comment: can anybody explain why i must use `select('count(account.id)')` instead of `select('count(account)')` ?

Comment: @Sliq - One reason is that the entity manager has no from method so it would not work.  Working code (no matter how ugly) is generally considered superior to non-working code.  You could in fact use $em->findAll('entity')->count() but that involves some additional overhead as all the entity records would be loaded.  By the way, Symdony does not require Doctrine so feel free to use your own database access library.

Answer (score 69):

Here is another way to format the query:

```
return $repository->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->select('count(u.id)')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Comment: Using the fluent interface is a different approach that is very helpful in case you intend to write static queries. If there is the need to toggle where conditions for example executing each method on it's own has it's advantages as well.

Comment: You can write this `return ($qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('u'))->select($qb->expr()->count('u.id'))->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();`

Comment: Just notice - do not use addSelect() for this, even in xdebug watch, this makes it not work.

Answer (score 35):

It's better to move all logic of working with database to repositores.

So in controller you write

```php
/* you can also inject "FooRepository $repository" using autowire */
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Foo::class);
$count = $repository->count();
```

And in `Repository/FooRepository.php`

```php
public function count()
{
    $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('t');
    return $qb
        ->select('count(t.id)')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

It's better to move `$qb = ...` to separate row in case you want to make complex expressions like

```php
public function count()
{
    $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('t');
    return $qb
        ->select('count(t.id)')
        ->where($qb->expr()->isNotNull('t.fieldName'))
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->orX(
            $qb->expr()->in('t.fieldName2', 0),
            $qb->expr()->isNull('t.fieldName2')
        ))
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

Also think about caching your query result - http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#caching-drivers

```php
public function count()
{
    $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('t');
    return $qb
        ->select('count(t.id)')
        ->getQuery()
        ->useQueryCache(true)
        ->useResultCache(true, 3600)
        ->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

In some simple cases using `EXTRA_LAZY` entity relations is good
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html

Answer (score 22):

If you need to count a more complex query, with `groupBy`, `having` etc... You can borrow from `Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator`:

```
$paginator = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator($query);
$totalRows = count($paginator);
```

Comment: Useful, but please note: this solution will work for queries on a single entity- with complex select statements, it will just refuse to work.

Comment: this solution produces additional query like `SELECT COUNT(*) AS dctrn_count FROM (_ORIGINAL_SQL_) dctrn_result) dctrn_table`
which is actually nothing special but well known COUNT(*) solution

Comment: $paginator->getTotalItemCount() would be a solution too

Answer (score 17):

Since `Doctrine 2.6` it is possible to use `count()` method directly from `EntityRepository`. For details see the link.

https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/77e3e5c96c1beec7b28443c5b59145eeadbc0baf/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php#L161

Comment: Yes, it looks like a great solution and works for more simple cases (you can pass criteria for filtering the counting), but I didn't manage to get it to work for criteria with associations (filtering by associations).  See related post here: https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/6290

Answer (score 6):

Example working with grouping, union and stuff.

Problem:

```
 $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
     ->select('m.id', 'rm.id')
     ->from('Model', 'm')
     ->join('m.relatedModels', 'rm')
     ->groupBy('m.id');
```

For this to work possible solution is to use custom hydrator and this weird thing
called 'CUSTOM OUTPUT WALKER HINT':

```
class CountHydrator extends AbstractHydrator
{
    const NAME = 'count_hydrator';
    const FIELD = 'count';

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected function hydrateAllData()
    {
        return (int)$this->_stmt->fetchColumn(0);
    }
}
class CountSqlWalker extends SqlWalker
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function walkSelectStatement(AST\SelectStatement $AST)
    {
        return sprintf("SELECT COUNT(*) AS %s FROM (%s) AS t", CountHydrator::FIELD, parent::walkSelectStatement($AST));
    }
}

$doctrineConfig->addCustomHydrationMode(CountHydrator::NAME, CountHydrator::class);
// $qb from example above
$countQuery = clone $qb->getQuery();
// Doctrine bug ? Doesn't make a deep copy... (as of "doctrine/orm": "2.4.6")
$countQuery->setParameters($this->getQuery()->getParameters());
// set custom 'hint' stuff
$countQuery->setHint(Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER, CountSqlWalker::class);

$count = $countQuery->getResult(CountHydrator::NAME);
```

Comment: I'd rather just write a native query than to deal with that Rube Goldberg code.

Comment: That's a good example of how shitty Symfony is: Something simple like a basic everyday SQL-count needs to be solved with totally complicated self-written stuff... wow, i mean, just wow! Still thanks to Sergey for this answer!

Answer (score 5):

For people who are using only Doctrine DBAL and not the Doctrine ORM, they will not be able to access the `getQuery()` method because it doesn't exists. They need to do something like the following.

```
$qb = new QueryBuilder($conn);
$count = $qb->select("count(id)")->from($tableName)->execute()->fetchColumn(0);
```

Answer (score 5):

To count items after some number of items (offset), $qb->setFirstResults() cannot be applied in this case, as it works not as a condition of query, but as an offset of query result for a range of items selected (i. e. setFirstResult cannot be used togather with COUNT at all). So to count items, which are left I simply did the following:

```
   //in repository class:
   $count = $qb->select('count(p.id)')
      ->from('Products', 'p')
      ->getQuery()
      ->getSingleScalarResult();

    return $count;

    //in controller class:
    $count = $this->em->getRepository('RepositoryBundle')->...

    return $count-$offset;
```

Anybody knows more clean way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following method to your repository should allow you to call `$repo->getCourseCount()` from your Controller.

```
/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getCourseCount()
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb
        ->select('count(course.id)')
        ->from('CRMPicco\Component\Course\Model\Course', 'course')
    ;

    $query = $qb->getQuery();

    return $query->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the number of data by using the count function.

```
$query = $this->dm->createQueryBuilder('AppBundle:Items')
                    ->field('isDeleted')->equals(false)
                    ->getQuery()->count();
```

Comment: its not working, count is not a function

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony 6 this is probably the easiest way:

```html
$this->manager()->getRepository(SomeEntity::class)->count(['field' => $value])
```