# How can I do "count(*)" using Symfony2 Doctrine ORM

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, count

How can I perform `count(*)` operation using Symfony2 Doctrine ORM ?
Without knowing the Entity class name and fields.

I got query builder to my class and I want to perform `count(*)` action.

I am doing the following:

```
public function count(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder)
    {
        $countQuery = clone queryBuilder;
        $countQuery->select('count(*)');
        $countQuery->setParameters(queryBuilder->getParameters());


        return $countQuery->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
    }
```

This returns the following error: `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 13 near '*) FROM Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Product': Error: '*' is not defined.`

DQL looks like this: `SELECT count(*) FROM Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Product Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Product ORDER BY name desc, description asc`

Any ideas? How to do it without specifying the column name ?

Comment: You need to specify which field you want to count because you are use orm.

Comment: So there is no way to go around without not telling the field name ? What when the id field is going to have other name ?

Comment: Yepp. you can do it using `count(id) as other`.

Comment: But the problem is i will not know the entity class structure, fields name and so

Comment: check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088026/how-would-i-do-mysql-count-in-doctrine2

Comment: i manage to do it without field name, just counting over the class name

`select('count(' . $countQuery->getEntityManager()->getRepository($countQuery->getRootEntities()[0])->getClassName() . ')')`

Comment: For what it's worth, this is another way to do it: `$repository->createQueryBuilder('WHATEVER')->select('count(WHATEVER)');` (if you provide a name to the query builder, you can use it in the count).