# How can I count the numbers of rows that a DQL query returned?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I want to count number of rows whose return from DQL query,how i do this?
here is my DQL query:

```
$items=$em->createQuery("select i.unitPrice,i.quantity,i.linetotal,i.description from InvoicesInvoicesBundle:Invoiceshasitems i where i.invoiceid='".$id."'");
$itemdata=$items->getResult();
```

Comment: do you want to show the serial number along the result? as 1,2,3.. or just the total number of records as 34 65 etc without any other data??

Comment: Use count http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Count()

```
$items=$em->createQuery("select COUNT(i.unitPrice)
                         from InvoicesInvoicesBundle:Invoiceshasitems i
                          where i.invoiceid='".$id."'");
    $itemdata=$items->getResult();
```

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

you should bookmark the above link if you are working regularly on DQL.

Comment: i used your code but this shows error like this [Syntax Error] line 0, col 24: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got ','

Comment: try the updated query. may be ur db allows only 1 column in count, use the column that always have a value and i think unit price is the right one

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
 $qbTotal = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
 $qbTotal->select('count(i)')
            ->from('InvoicesInvoicesBundle:Invoiceshasitems', 'i')
            ->where('i.invoiceid = :id')
            ->setParameter('id', $id)
             ;
    
 $queryTotal = $qbTotal->getQuery();
 $totalItems = $queryTotal->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, @Praveesh has the answer though there is a slight typo in it.  Should be:id instead of ?id.

But this link has earned me 680 reps so I'm pretty sure it is correct: [Count Rows in Doctrine QueryBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214471/count-rows-in-doctrine-querybuilder/9215880#9215880)

Comment: hehe the lucky punch - others are working hard for their reps :-) 680 and counting ... but honestly i came across your answer and upvoted it months ago, too. greetings