# Symfony2 Doctrine get count all as integer

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I want to get count of all records in DB. I haven't found one recommended way to do this. So I've built in my entity repo this function:

```
public function countAll()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('post')
        ->select('COUNT(post)')
        ->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult()
        ;
}
```

and it's OK, because it returns me count of all items. I use FOSRestBundle, so my action in controller looks like:

```
public function getPostsCountAction() {
    return $this->em->getRepository('KamilTestBundle:Post')->countAll();
}
```

and result at the addres posts/count.json looks like:

```
"16"
```

But... I want to take this value as integer. I don't know why QueryBuilder returns it as string. Even if I use ->getQuery()->getResult() and dump this output it's also string, not integer.

How can I take this value as integer? It is possible?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9215880/1794894

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[intval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) will return the number representation of a string.

While it might be a slippery thing to use this, you should be 100% fine since you know you will be getting only numbers.

```
public function countAll()
{
    return intval($this->createQueryBuilder('post')
        ->select('COUNT(post)')
        ->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult());
}
```

Comment: Mhm, when I use "COUNT(post)" it always will be integer. But maybe I can do this with doctrine. For example: when I take complete entity id's of records are integers.

Comment: Doesn't my answer solve it? What other problems are you having?

Comment: Or `return (int) $this->createQueryBuilder('post')....->getSingleScalarResult()`.

Answer (score -3):

```
return count($this->em->getRepository('KamilTestBundle:Post')->findAll());
```

This should return an integer ([count](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.count.php)).

An alternative could be typecasting:

```
 return (int) $this->em->getRepository('KamilTestBundle:Post')->countAll();
```

This will just convert your string to an int and should be more efficient than counting in PHP.

Comment: Yes, but this solution isn't good idea. It's OK when i have 16 posts, but when it will be number like 16000? It doesn't make sense to take all posts and count it on PHP side.

Comment: True, but you didn't specify you have such a large number of entries. Lettings the db query count them is the better idea in this case.

Comment: I don't know how many entities I will have in future :) I always prefer to count items with DB query.

Comment: Try typecasting as I suggested, see if it works. I don't understand why I am getting downvotes for a plausible answer.