# symfony 2 get count of repository find

Tags: php, symfony

i am working with database data via repository.

I need to get quantity of found rows.

```
$followers = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Follower')->findBy(array(
                'user' => $followedUser,
                'follower' => $user
        ));
```

I have tried to search functions, which return repository find count, but didnt found any.

How should i get the count?

Thank you.

Comment: The `findOneBy` method returns always 1 row.

Comment: You have to use `findBy` instead. Alternatively you can also do this with a query builder and get an array result. The array count will be your `count(*)`.

Comment: yes i have findBy there.. just a typo.

Comment: count($followers) will do the trick.  But if all you need is the count and none of the data then try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214471/count-rows-in-doctrine-querybuilder/9215880#9215880

Answer (score 1):

Working solution @ 2019

```
$followersCount = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Follower')->count([
            'user' => $followedUser,
            'follower' => $user
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return all the rows the you can just count($followers) as $followers is a collection that is countable.

If you just want the count and do not want to return a collection of Follower Entities, then you'll need to use createQueryBuilder and select just the count, ensuring to use getSingleScalarResult() to return the count value.

As Cerad notes, check out [Count Rows in Doctrine QueryBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214471/count-rows-in-doctrine-querybuilder/9215880#9215880) Which goes into detail of latter option.