# Get count query results via getSingleScalarResult() and groupBy() - exception

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, group-by

I want get results of my query (with limit 10) + count possible results.
I know there is similar questions and answers.

[for example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214471/count-rows-in-doctrine-querybuilder#answer-9215880)

but if i trying get count possible rows (via `getSingleScalarResult()`) i will get excepton: `The query returned multiple rows. Change the query or use a different result function like getScalarResult().`

```
    $query = $repository
        ->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->select('COUNT(t.katId)', 't.hotel', 't.title', 't.desc', 'picture', 'MIN(t.price) AS price');

    $query->where('t.visible = (:visible)')->setParameter('visible', 1);

    // + some wheres, where in, more than....

    $query->groupBy('t.hotel');
    $query->setMaxResults(10);

    echo $query->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
    exit();
```

I just need one integer whitch represent all results from my query.
How can i get this count number? Ideal in one shot to db.

---

**EDIT:**

if i remove `$query->groupBy('t.hotel');` and in select keep only `->select('count(t.katId)');` **then it work**.  But i need `groupBy` because it makes real count of results.

---

**SOLUTION**

I divided it on two queries so - to get results i rolled back changes to state before trying any count information, and make clone this query (before set `setMaxResults` and `groupBy`), change select (keep all wheres) and get count information.

**I will be grateful if someone offers better solution**

1. Get results:

   - removed COUNT() from select
   - asking for results changed to 'normal' `->getArrayResults`
2. Get count:

   ```
   $q = clone $query;

   $q->select('count(distinct t.hotel) as count');
   $r = $q->getQuery()->getArrayResult();

   echo $r[0]['count'];
   exit();
   ```

Comment: If you just keep count in your select  ->select('COUNT(t.katId)'); it's work ? just for test

Comment: Nope. I keep in select only `count(t.katId)` and try `->getResult()` and `->getArrayResult()` but i get array with a lot of indexes and values like array(144) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [1]=>
    string(3) "111"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [1]=>
    string(3) "226"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [1]=>
    string(3) "151"
  }......

Answer (score 1):

If you need keep the groupBy:

```
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('t')
$query->select('COUNT(t.katId)', 't.hotel', 't.title', 't.desc', 'picture', 'MIN(t.price) AS price');
$query->from(ENTITY STRING, 't', 't.hotel');  //here defined your array result key
$query->where('t.visible = (:visible)')->setParameter('visible', 1);
$query->groupBy('t.hotel');
$query->setMaxResults(10);

echo $query->getQuery()->getScalarResult();
exit();
```

Edit : New edit works ?

Comment: If you need keep getSingleScalarResult you must delete groupBy. If you need keep groupBy you must replace singleScalar by getScalarResult. Working ?

Comment: If i use solution 'keep the groupBy' (`->getScalarResult()` returns array so no echo but print_r()) i get the same array as with `->getArrayResult` something like: Array ( [0] => Array ( [1] => 111 ) [1] => Array ( [1] => 226 ) [2] => Array ( [1] => 151 ) [3] =.....

Comment: I try to defined your result array key because the SQL request is correct, but the key don't display the name of hotel... try the new edit.

Comment: We are move on :) Array result key is not significant for me. But count your query show me how many rows with same `t.hotel` for result `t.hotel` i have in table. So in result i have 10 hotels and in count i see how much records `t.hotel` i have for same value `t.hotel` in table... but my point was see how many results rows i will get from this select (one integer) without pull all rows (without limit).

Comment: and maybe is better for result array key use `-> select('count(t.katId) as myNiceKey', 't.hotel'...)`

Answer (score 0):

You are only interested in COUNT(t.katId), so you should drop other returned fields 't.hotel', 't.title', etc.
The result will then contain a single return value (single scalar result), so `$query->setMaxResults(10)` is not needed.

Comment: I was try keep in select only `count(t.katId)` + remove `setMaxResults(10)` and get `$query->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();` but same exception.