# Count results for group by query

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a complex query which group bys multiple columns, this is an example

```php
$queryBuilder
    ->join('e.something', 's')
    ->where('...')
    ->addGroupBy('e.id s.someField');
```

Using `->getQuery()->getResults()` returns me an array of entities like I'd expect.

```php
[
    0 => App\Entity\ExampleEntity,
    1 => App\Entity\ExampleEntity
]
```

If I try to count the results returned using a select like so:

```php
$queryBuilder
    ->select('COUNT(e.id)')
    ->join('e.something', 's')
    ->where('...')
    ->addGroupBy('e.id s.someField');
```

I am returned an array of arrays, inside each array is the count. This isn't what I want. Removing the group by I'm given the correct result however the group by is required.

```php
[
    [
        1 => '11',
    ],
    [
        1 => '4',
    ]
]
```

I'm stuck on how I can count the results of the group by. I have tried using distinct and I also do not want to count in PHP.

Comment: I don't really understand, if you add a group by, it's quite normal the count uses the group by !
What's the logic behind adding a group by to not use it in the count ?

Comment: Not saying it's not normal I just don't know how to get around it. I only shared a simplified version but the query is used for a list page which filters and sorts

Comment: Dupplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43202217/get-count-query-results-via-getsinglescalarresult-and-groupby-exception

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get count query results via getSingleScalarResult() and groupBy() - exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43202217/get-count-query-results-via-getsinglescalarresult-and-groupby-exception)