# Symfony/Doctrine2 and Associative entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Usually when querying in a custom repository class, I use something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM BundleName:Entity
```

But how do I do for associative entity ?

I have an entity "Ticket" and an entity "Tag".
It's a ManyToMany relation.

In phpMyAdmin, I've got a ticket_tag associative table but how do I get it with Doctrine ?

Thank you

Comment: How did you configure your relations in doctrine ? If it is a real ManyToMany, why do you need those associative objects ? You should have a getter on both sides to get the related objects or use DQL query to get either one by specific conditions.

Comment: I have got getters on both sides, but I want to do more than that.
Let's say I want to get the number of tickets for each tag. I don't want to loop on ALL tickets (ticket->getTags()). If my user has got 10k tickets for exemple.

Comment: My working SQL is the following : SELECT tag.id, tag.name, count(tt.ticket_id) FROM ticket_tag tt, savBundle:Tag tag WHERE tag.id = tt.tag_id GROUP BY tag.id, tag.name. So ideally, I would want to know how to get my ticket_tag table with doctrine

Comment: Getting a scaler value is a [completely different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214471/count-rows-in-doctrine-querybuilder/9215880#9215880).  You probably need to be a bit more specific and perhaps visit the [dql section](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/query-builder.html) of the docs.

Comment: In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214471/count-rows-in-doctrine-querybuilder/9215880#9215880], we use the bundle entity from symfony, but I want to use a table that is NOT an entity in my symfony project. I can't just do the BundleName:EntityName thing

Comment: No idea what you are asking for.  Use sql if you need to fetch stuff from an unmapped table.  But I don't see how you can have an associative entity that is not an entity.  In other words, update your question with your actual question and maybe someone can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `createQueryBuilder` to handle your custom query requirement, in case if you are having a valid relationship over entities. for example: 
Inside ticket repository you should handle like this, if you want to do more operations then you should learn more from here: https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/doctrine/repository.html

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
     ->select('count(t.id) as total_ticket, tag.id as tagId')
     ->leftJoin('t.tags', 'tag')
     ->groupBy('tag.id')
;

return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: to see/learn more relevant methods related createQueryBuilder please have look here https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/query-builder.html