# Show aggregate count of large number of entities in Symfony 3.4 Easy Admin bundle

Tags: symfony, symfony2-easyadmin, easyadmin

I'm trying to show a count of related entities for an entity List view, but there's too many so it runs out of memory (it does a simple `count($this->relatedEntities)`) in the Entity.

Any idea how/where I can override the `ListController` of `QueryBuilder` to add an aggeregated `COUNT()` column?

I tried extending the `AdminController` and hooking into the `findAll()` function (to manually add a count to each object), but that doesn't give me a list of entities but a `Pagerfanta` object.

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9215880/4716084

Comment: additionally you can check extra lazy loading or eager loading, both approaches avoid the extra sql queries for related entities when you're just interested in the count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I fixed it:

Overriding the renderTemplate in custom AdminController:

```
protected function renderTemplate($actionName, $templatePath, array $parameters = array())
{
    if ($actionName === 'list' && $this->entity['class'] === ClassA::class) {
        //piggyback on virtual property 'count'
        $parameters['fields']['count']['servicecounts'] = $this->MyEntityRepository->getCounts();
    }

    return $this->render($templatePath, $parameters);
}
```

easy_admin config:

```
  list:
    fields:
    - { property: 'count', template: 'count.html.twig' }
```

count.html.twig:

```
{{ field_options.servicecounts[item.id] }}
```

getCounts function:

```
public function getCounts()
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb
        ->select('s.id, count(ce.recordId)')
        ->from(ClassA::class, 's')
        ->leftJoin(ClassB::class, 'ce', Join::WITH, 's.id = ce.service')
        ->groupBy('s.id')
    ;

    $results = [];
    foreach ($qb->getQuery()->execute() as $row) {
        $results[$row['id']] = $row[1];
    }

    return $results;

}
```