# Symfony query builder, count search result

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

It's my query builder:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('cl');
$qb->select('cl')
   ->andWhere('cl.name LIKE :query')
   ->setParameter('query',  '%param%');

//$totalrows = ????

$qb->setMaxResults(10);

$results = $qb->getQuery()->getScalarResult();
```

How I can count all search results?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214471/count-rows-in-doctrine-querybuilder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count Rows in Doctrine QueryBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214471/count-rows-in-doctrine-querybuilder)