# Performing count() on odm query (cursor) does not return "0" if data is empty in Symfony- MongoDB-ODM

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-odm

Performing `count()` on odm query (cursor) does not return "0" if data is empty in Symfony- MongoDB-ODM

```php
$query = $this->dm->createQueryBuilder('AppBundle:DocumentName');
$count = $query->getQuery()->count();
```

The var `$count` always returns value greater than zero ("0"). Even if there is no data in document

**Note : Converting cursor to arrays consumes more memory, Please Excuse this method.**

Comment: possible duplicate [Count Rows in Doctrine QueryBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214471/count-rows-in-doctrine-querybuilder)

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```
$count = $query->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Regards

Comment: Please note that question is about ODM, not ORM. ODM does not have a `getSingleScalarResult` method.

Answer (score 0):

you can use AggregationBuilder. Try this code in your documentNameRepository:

```
$qb = $this->createAggregationBuilder('Document\DocumentName');
$qb->count('nb_documents');
$results = $qb->execute();
return $results;
```

You can execute where operation before the count like below:

```
$qb->match()
   ->field('field_name')
   ->equals(10);
```

You can execute limit and skip operation before the count like below:

```
$qb->skip(10)
   ->limit(100);
```

You can read [the documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/1.2/reference/aggregation-builder.html#aggregation-pipeline-stages).

Comment: sorry, how could i add where conditions?, including limit and skip ?

Comment: I added this to my answer.